# Отправка писем на email средствами php

Tags: php

Зашел на одну статью, как порекомендовали, сделал настройки как там, даже скрипт оттуда взял, но результатов нет, внизу скрипт

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Simple Mail</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$addr = $_POST['addr'];
$theme = $_POST['theme'];
$text = $_POST['text'];
if (isset($addr) && isset($theme) && isset($text)
        && $addr != "" && $theme != "" && $text != "") {
    if (mail($addr, $theme, $text, "From: мое мыло")) {
        echo "<h3>Сообщение отправлено</h3>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<h3>При отправке сообщения возникла ошибка</h3>";
    }
}
?>
<form action="mailer.php" method="post">
<p>
    <label for="addr">eMail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="addr" id="addr" size="30" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="theme">Тема письма:</label>
    <input type="text" name="theme" id="theme" size="30" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="text">Текст письма:</label>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="20" name="text" id="text"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Настройка php.ini

> `SMTP = 
> smtp_port = 25
> sendmail_from = 
> sendmail_path = "C:\web\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\ -t"`

Настройка sendmail.ini

> `smtp_server=smtp.mail.ru
> smtp_port=25
> default_domain=mail.ru
> error_logfile=error.log
> debug_logfile=debug.log
> auth_username=мое мыло
> auth_password=мой пасс
> pop3_server=pop.mail.ru
> pop3_username=мое мыло
> pop3_password=мой пасс
> force_sender=мое мыло
> hostname=mail.ru`

Вот статья: [PHP mail под Windows. Отправка почты из PHP скриптов](http://www.simplecoding.org/php-mail-pod-windows.html)

Answer (score 1):

Если сервер ваш и настройки SMTP правильны, то всё предельно просто - [смотрим статью](http://php.su/functions/?mail) и достаточно глянуть в самый низ, где указан "**Пример 4. Отправка сложной email.**". А если у вас хостинг, с поддержкой php, то о настройках как бы и задумываться не надо - практически любой хостинг (платный!) эту услугу предоставляют автоматом.

P.S. Мелькнула мысль, что вы это пробуете на Денвере. Тогда смотрите папочку "*WebServers\tmp\!sendmail*", там все ваши отправленные письма, но в инет они уходить не будут.

**UPD:** *"...не на денвере а на XAMPP..."*  Так значит это уже второй ваш аналогичный вопрос. В прощлом вопросе я вам в комментариях [ссылочку давал](http://makegood.ru/tools/8/#3). Просмотрите её. Может кое-чем поможет.

Comment: внет не на денвере а на XAMPP и хостинг только пока что локальный!

Comment: с локального сервера ты отправишь только в папку TMP у себя если не настроены пробросы во внешнюю сеть!

Так что скорее всего все отправляется, но локально и просто в папку. тестируй на нормальном хостинге и все отправится.

Answer (score 1):

Есть библиотека удобная `http://webi.ru/webi_files/php_libmail.html`

Comment: пасибо, все теперь заработало)))

Answer (score 1):

1. Посмотрите логи, может, ошибка там записана.
2. Куда вы ее отправляете? Если куда-нибудь на маил.ру, то неудивительно, что оно может просто не дойти до ящика. Фильтры вырежут его и все.

С Сайта php.net

> Windows-реализация mail() во многом
> отличается от Unix-реализации.
> Во-первых, она не использует локальный
> экзешник для составления сообщений, а
> работает лишь по прямым сокетам, что
> означает, что MTA должен прослушивать
> сетевой сокет (который может
> находиться на локальной или удалённой
> машине). Во-вторых, специальные
> шапки/headers вроде From:, Cc:, Bcc: и
> Date: не интерпретируются MTA, а
> разбираются в PHP. PHP < 4.3
> поддерживал только header-элемент Cc:
> (и был чувствительным к регистру). PHP
>
> > = 4.3 поддерживает все элементы шапки и нечувствителен к регистру символов.

Наконец сформируйте нормальные заголовки письму, например:

```
$headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

/* дополнительные шапки */
$headers .= "From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com\r\n";
```